# How to add a scroll View

Tags: java, android

I want to add a scroll view to tablerow in onClick I already have the code but it crashes Unfortunately,has stopped

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a
>   parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

I Just Created a GridView when i click the item of GridView it show this table layout with rows and this is my onClick Code

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                        long arg3) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      //Result tr
      String st = "insert into ChecksItems (Check_ID,Item_ID,QTY,UnitPrice,TotalPrice,DicountValue,Tax_Value,Adj_Value,NetPrice,Serial,Fired,Fired_Time,Voided,Voided_Time,Voided_Reason,P_On_Check,Complement,Status,IsModifier,Ref_Mod_Item,IsAssimbly,Ref_Ass_Item,Taxable,NoServiceCharge,Num_Fired,Num_Print,Server_ID,P_On_Report,Check_ID_Combine,Round_Check_Fired,Void_Effect_Invn,Promo_ID,Orig_Price,Officer,Comp_Reason_ID,End_Serial_Count,Discount_ID,Disc_Reason_ID,Hold,Hold_Time,Voided_By,Comp_By,Disc_By) 
                   values (" + String.valueOf(MenuListView.Check_ID) + "," + alphabets.get(arg2).get("Item_ID").toString() + ",1," + alphabets.get(arg2).get("Price").toString() + "," + alphabets.get(arg2).get("Price").toString() + ",0,0,0," + alphabets.get(arg2).get("Price").toString() + "," + String.valueOf(MenuListView.Item_Serial) + ",0,GetDate(),0,GetDate(),0,'" + alphabets.get(arg2).get("PrintOnChick").toString() + "',0,'New',0,0,0,0,'" + alphabets.get(arg2).get("Taxable").toString() + "','" + alphabets.get(arg2).get("NoServiceCharge").toString() + "',0,0,0,'" + alphabets.get(arg2).get("PrintOnReport").toString() + "',0,1,0,0," + alphabets.get(arg2).get("Price").toString() + ",0,0,0,0,0,0,GetDate(),0,0,0)";

      if (ConnectionClass.executeUpdate(st)) {
          MenuListView.Item_Serial++;
          final TableRow tr_head2 = new TableRow(GridDynamic.this);
          tr_head2.setId(10);
          tr_head2.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fab_label_background));
          tr_head2.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
          tr_head2.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                        TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

          TextView label_category2 = new TextView(GridDynamic.this);
          label_category2.setId(20);
          label_category2.setText("1");
          label_category2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
          label_category2.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
          label_category2.setTextSize(18);
          label_category2.setPadding(20, 3, 20, 3);
          tr_head2.addView(label_category2);// add the column to the table row here

          TextView label_quantity_amount2 = new TextView(GridDynamic.this);
          label_quantity_amount2.setId(21);// define id that must be unique
          label_quantity_amount2.setText(alphabets.get(arg2).get("Name").toString()); // set the text for the header
          label_quantity_amount2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); // set the color
          label_quantity_amount2.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
          label_quantity_amount2.setTextSize(18);
          label_quantity_amount2.setPadding(20, 3, 20, 3); // set the padding (if required)
          tr_head2.addView(label_quantity_amount2); // add the column to the table row here

          TextView label_total_price_amount2 = new TextView(GridDynamic.this);
          label_total_price_amount2.setId(22);// define id that must be unique
          label_total_price_amount2.setText(alphabets.get(arg2).get("Price").toString()); // set the text for the header
          label_total_price_amount2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); // set the color
          label_total_price_amount2.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
          label_total_price_amount2.setTextSize(18);
          label_total_price_amount2.setPadding(20, 3, 20, 3); // set the padding (if required)
          tr_head2.addView(label_total_price_amount2); // add the column to the table row here

          tableLayout.addView(tr_head2, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                        TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

       ScrollView scroll = new ScrollView(GridDynamic.this);
       scroll.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
       scroll.addView(tr_head2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*EDIT*: note that this answer was for original question asked here (re. deleting table row)....question has since been edited.

When you're adding row to table set tag associated with it

```
        tableRow.setTag(<some key associated with this row>);
        tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
```

Then you can do following to delete the row.

```
        View view = tableLayout.findViewWithTag(key);
        if (view != null) {
            tableLayout.removeView(view);
        }
```

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Harooney can you edit your question above to show code where you're doing this (or perhaps might be better to add new question)

Comment: I think it would probably have been better to add new question (or at least appended your question to original one rather than replacing it completely)....it will be confusing for people viewing this and see accepted answer which is no longer about the question shown).

Comment: I added a new question you can check it